# htaccess - redirect removing part of url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to remove **ALL** the ***-del*** and ***.html*** like this

example:

http://website.com/test-del/test2-del/test3-del.html

http://website.com/test/test2/test3

Thanks in advance.

My curreny httaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)-del(?:(/.*)?|\.html)$ /$1$2 [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply but it doesn't seem to be working. It just takes me to the 404 page.
It also adds this to the url ?_route_=

Comment: HI, maybe i didn't make myself clear in my question.
I want to delete all the -del in the url (there are 2 or more in every url)

http://website.com/test-del/test2-del.html

So if i visit http://example.com/test-del/test2 it will not work.


I will have to visit the url without the -del

Comment: If i visit

http://website.com/test-del/test2/test3-del/test4-del.html

With your rule it will redirect to something like that

http://website.com/test?_route_=test-del/test2/test3-del/test4-del.html

Comment: Check full .htaccess in your question and make sure to clear your browser cache before you test this.